# Understanding different kind of loops in R (for, repeated, while)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I would like to understand loops in R by finding the average of a vector x <- 1:10

There are 3 different kinds of loops and I have the code to solve this problem, but I need a breakdown of each one to understand what each line does.

The first one is a for loop.

```
x <- 1:10
total <- length(x)
x_sum <- 0
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  x_sum <- x_sum + x[i]
}
x_sum / total
## [1] 5.5
```

I don't understand why `x_sum <- 0` in the initial part, and why `x_sum <- x_sum + x[i]`. Is i the seq of 1,2,...,10?

The second one is a repeat loop.

```
x <- 1:10
total <- length(x)
x_sum <- 0
i <- 1
repeat {
  x_sum <- x_sum + x[i]
  if (i == total) break
  i <- i + 1
}
x_sum / total
## [1] 5.5
```

I don't really understand this one either and a thorough explanation line by line would be great. The variable i is really throwing me off.

Answer (score 5):

**x_sum initialization**

`x_sum` is initially set to 0 because the later statement

```
x_sum <- x_sum + x[i]
```

will only work if all variables on the right hand side are defined.  Had `x_sum` not been defined this statement would have issued an error the first time it was invoked.  The first time through the loop this will set `x_sum` to `x_sum+x[1]` but `x_sum` is 0 so `x_sum` will be set to the value of `x[1]` which is 1.  On subsequent iterations the prior value of `x_sum` will be used.

**i iteration**

A `for` loop of the form `for(i in v) { ...body... }` runs the body once for each element of vector `v`.   In this case the vector is `seq_along(x)` whose value we can display explicitly like this:

```
> x <- 1:10
> seq_long(x)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

so the first time the loop runs i is set to 1, the second time to 2 and so on.  The last time the loop is run i is set to 10.

**instrumenting the code**

We can find out what is going on by adding `cat` statements.  We will show it for the `for` statement:

```
x <- 1:10
total <- length(x)
x_sum <- 0
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  cat("A: i:", i, "x[i]:", x[i], "x_sum:", x_sum, "\n")  # <----------
  x_sum <- x_sum + x[i]
  cat("B: i:", i, "x[i]:", x[i], "x_sum:", x_sum, "\n\n")  # <----------
}
x_sum / total
## [1] 5.5
```

Running the above we get this output.  Each iteration starts with A and ends with B so on the first iteration `i` is 1 and `x[i]` is 1 and `x_sum` is 0 and `x_sum` gets incremented from 0 on the A line to 1 on the B line.  On the second iteration `i` is 2 and `x[i]` is 2 and `x_sum` gets incremented from 1 to 3 and so on. (Continued further on below.)

```
A: i: 1 x[i]: 1 x_sum: 0 
B: i: 1 x[i]: 1 x_sum: 1 

A: i: 2 x[i]: 2 x_sum: 1 
B: i: 2 x[i]: 2 x_sum: 3 

A: i: 3 x[i]: 3 x_sum: 3 
B: i: 3 x[i]: 3 x_sum: 6 

A: i: 4 x[i]: 4 x_sum: 6 
B: i: 4 x[i]: 4 x_sum: 10 

A: i: 5 x[i]: 5 x_sum: 10 
B: i: 5 x[i]: 5 x_sum: 15 

A: i: 6 x[i]: 6 x_sum: 15 
B: i: 6 x[i]: 6 x_sum: 21 

A: i: 7 x[i]: 7 x_sum: 21 
B: i: 7 x[i]: 7 x_sum: 28 

A: i: 8 x[i]: 8 x_sum: 28 
B: i: 8 x[i]: 8 x_sum: 36 

A: i: 9 x[i]: 9 x_sum: 36 
B: i: 9 x[i]: 9 x_sum: 45 

A: i: 10 x[i]: 10 x_sum: 45 
B: i: 10 x[i]: 10 x_sum: 55 

> x_sum / total
[1] 5.5
> ## [1] 5.5
```

Try instrumenting the `repeat` loop in the same manner.

**unrolling the loop**

In fact the initialization and for loop is equivalent to running this:

```
x_sum <- 0
x_sum <- x_sum + x[1]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[2]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[3]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[4]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[5]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[6]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[7]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[8]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[9]
x_sum <- x_sum + x[10]
```